# Quick sort of chars in String

Tags: java, string, sorting, char, quicksort

*I am trying to sort characters from string in alphabetic order.*
**For example : program = agmoprr**
*This is my code and I don't see how can I fix it. Any hint or tip? :)*

```
    public static String quicksort(String y){
    String x = "";
    char[] a = new char[y.length()];
    int i = 0;
    int j = a.length;
    if(j-i < 0) return y;
    int m = i+(j-i)/2;
    char b = a[m];
    a[m] = a[i];
    a[i] = b;
    int r = i+1;
    for(int s = r; s!=j; s=s+1){
        if(a[s] < b)
        {
            char tmp = a[s];
            a[s] = a[r];
            a[r] = tmp;
            r=r+1;
        }
    }
    r=r-1;
    a[i] = a[r];
    a[r] = b;
    return x = quicksort(y);
}
```

Comment: What is the error/problem? If it's not compiling, please provide the stack trace. If the outputs are not sorted, please provide the test cases (and the incorrect output).

Comment: I am able to compile it, but when I run it through cmd, hundreds of at sorty.quicksort<sorty.java:26>
Which is line char b = a[m];

Comment: This code is very, very broken. Quicksort requires two points of recursion. Also, you  are not copying the data from the input string to the 'a' array, just the length. This is far, far from working.

Comment: Well.. http://pastebin.com/mXjeLCap
This is how I did it, but our professor wants it in public static String quicksort(String y) method...

Comment: That would be a very different question. Your pastebin looks sane, for a quicksort, so why not just pull the string handling code from your main method, and wrap it in a new method 'quicksort'?

Comment: Could you give me a hint how to do it so it would return x = quicksort(y); since x is a string with the same letters as y, but with the letters in ascending alphabetic order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should do recursion, without it you are not going to solve quicksort.
The below version works for me.

```
public class Quicksort {

char[] myArray;

public String sort(String myStr){

    if(myStr == null || myStr.length() == 0 || myStr.length() == 1){
        return null;
    }
    int length = myStr.length();
    int low =0,high = length -1;
    this.myArray = myStr.toCharArray(); 

    quickSort(low,high);
    return new String(myArray);

}

public static void quickSort(int low, int high){

    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    char tmp;

    int pivot = (low+high)/2;

    while (i <= j) {
        while(myArray[i] < myArray[pivot]){
            i++;
        }
        while(myArray[j] > myArray[pivot]){
            j--;
        }

        if(i <= j) {
            tmp = myArray[i];
            myArray[i] = myArray[j];
            myArray[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if(low < j){
        quickSort(low, j);
    }
    if(i < high){
        quickSort(i,high);
    }
    System.out.println(myArray);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey man, I really appriciate your help. I did it in similair way to you here : http://pastebin.com/mXjeLCap
but our professor told us to use the public static String quicksort(String y) method    and I just can't think of any solution to do it.

Comment: Hi Derik, i modified the code. As far as i understand, your professor might have given you that requirement on the method that is exposed to the users. In the above code, quickSort(myString) can be called from your main method/test case. It passes a string and gets a return value f string type.Internally it converts into a char array and it should not be a problem with your professor.

Comment: If you are still unhappy you can change the signature of the second quicksort method to quicksort(myString, int low, int high) and compare elements using myString.charAt[i,j or whatever]. But i am sure that the above solution will keep him happy